# How to exit main in haskell given a condition

Tags: haskell, error-handling, io, monads, exit-code

I have a main function that does a lot of IO. At one point, however, I want to check a variable like `not (null shouldBeNull)` exit the whole program, without continuing, with a linux exitcode 1 and output an error message.

I've tried playing around with `error "..."` like putting that in an `if`:

`if (not (null shouldBeNull)) error "something bad happened" else putStrLn "ok"`

but I get a `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)` :(.

Here's an altered snippet.

```
main :: IO ExitCode
main = do 
  --Get the file name using program argument
  args <- getArgs
  file <- readFile (args !! 0)
  putStrLn("\n")
  -- ... (some other io)
  -- [DO A CHECK HERE], exit according to check..
  -- ... (even more io)
  echotry <- system "echo success"
  rmtry <- system "rm -f test.txt"
  system "echo done."
```

As you may notice, I want to do the check where I've put `[DO A CHECK HERE]` comment above...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parse error is because you're missing the `then` keyword in your `if` expression.

```
if condition then truePart else falsePart
```

For exiting, a more appropriate choice than `error` might be to use one of the functions from `System.Exit`, for example [`exitFailure`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Exit.html#v%3aexitFailure).

So for example,

```
if not $ null shouldBeNull
    then do putStrLn "something bad happened"
            exitFailure
    else putStrLn "ok"
```

Comment: Or, not to print out an unimportant "ok", `import Control.Monad` and `when badThingHappened exitFailure`.